# How can I force an immediate update of Google Glass to latest release?

Tags: google-glass

When a new version of Google Glass XE operating system comes out (XE21 just came out recently), my Glass doesn't auto-update immediately.  I'd like to be able to trigger an auto-update.  It looks like I could download an image and do some adb work based on the images here: https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system

But I'm too lazy for that.  Isn't there an "adb update" command or something like that I can use to just quickly update Glass to the latest XE immediately?  My Glass is charged > 50% and has been sitting on a good WiFi connection for hours.  The updates for previous versions seemed to come days to weeks after the release announcement on twitter.

Comment: You don't meet the requirements for auto updating https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3226482?hl=en I have to issue a downvote because of your complete and total lack of researching before asking this question otherwise please detail if the update is pending and plugged in the question itself

Comment: Also note that not only must the battery be greater than 50%, automatic update will not work unless CURRENTLY plugged in.  I.e. Plugged in AND greater than 50%... not "OR".